# I provided personal information to a scam survey. What's my risk?

Tags: risk, scams, identity-theft

I filled out this survey to win a something. Then realized it was a scam. Felt really dumb. Anyhow, I gave my email, name, phone number and address. What can the do with the information I gave them?

Answer (score 1):

They will likely sell your information in a huge dataset used to spam people marketing garbage.